# Python type long vs C 'long long'

Tags: python, 64-bit, long-integer

I would like to represent a value as a 64bit signed `long`, such that values larger than `(2**63)-1` are represented as negative, however Python `long` has infinite precision. Is there a 'quick' way for me to achieve this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use [`ctypes.c_longlong`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_longlong):

```
>>> from ctypes import c_longlong as ll
>>> ll(2 ** 63 - 1)
c_longlong(9223372036854775807L)
>>> ll(2 ** 63)
c_longlong(-9223372036854775808L)
>>> ll(2 ** 63).value
-9223372036854775808L
```

This is really **only** an option if you know for sure that a `signed long long` will be 64 bits wide on the target machine(s).

**Edit:** [jorendorff's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764548/python-type-long-vs-c-long-long/1764621#1764621) of defining a class for 64 bit numbers is appealing. Ideally you want to minimize the number of explicit class creations.

Using `c_longlong`, you could do something like this (**note:** Python 3.x only!):

```
from ctypes import c_longlong

class ll(int):
    def __new__(cls, n):
        return int.__new__(cls, c_longlong(n).value)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return ll(super().__add__(other))

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return ll(other.__add__(self))

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return ll(super().__sub__(other))

    def __rsub__(self, other):
        return ll(other.__sub__(self))

    ...
```

In this way the result of `ll(2 ** 63) - 1` will indeed be `9223372036854775807`. This construction may result in a performance penalty though, so depending on what you want to do exactly, defining a class such as the above may not be worth it. When in doubt, use [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/timeit.html).

Answer (score 13):

Can you use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/)?  It has an int64 type that does exactly what you want.

```
In [1]: import numpy

In [2]: numpy.int64(2**63-1)
Out[2]: 9223372036854775807

In [3]: numpy.int64(2**63-1)+1
Out[3]: -9223372036854775808
```

It's transparent to users, unlike the ctypes example, and it's coded in C so it'll be faster than rolling your own class in Python.  Numpy may be bigger than the other solutions, but if you're doing numerical analysis, you will appreciate having it.

Answer (score 3):

The quickest thing is probably to truncate the result to 64 bits yourself:

```
def to_int64(n):
    n = n & ((1 << 64) - 1)
    if n > (1 << 63) - 1:
        n -= 1 << 64
    return n
```

You can of course define your own numeric type that automatically does this every time you do any sort of arithmetic operation:

```
class Int64:
    def __init__(self, n):
        if isinstance(n, Int64):
            n = n.val
        self.val = to_int64(n)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Int64(self.val + other)

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return Int64(other + self.val)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return Int64(self.val - other)

    ...
```

but that is not particularly "quick" to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the ctypes module, it is used to call foreign DLLs/libraries from python.
There a some data types that correspond to C types, for example

> class c_longlong