# Long Long Int in python

Tags: python

I have a task to calculate a sum of very big integers.
the sum could be over the limit of max value of int.
I'd like to use long long int type like in c to prevent this.
python is dynamic type language.
but there must be someway to declare this long long int type.
help me to declare long long int type in python.
thanks

Comment: It will take the `value` as long as you have enough memory :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764548/python-type-long-vs-c-long-long
Search you`r question on stack.

Comment: no matter how big they are, I think python will handle it. love python : )

Comment: You don't declare types in Python. That's why it is called a dynamic language.

Comment: thanks for answering. i love python

Comment: Python 3 `int` *has* no maximum value. Even in Python 2, where `int` had some (platform-specific) maximum, results were promoted to the unbounded `long` type as necessary. There was virtually no semantic difference between `int` and `long`; the distinction represented an implementation detail that was swept under the rug in Python 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to.

```
>>> sum([
...     1243926478235632786572938657832682396538279658237956832976482375678239659782365,
...     23590237589734985720423803758031640192748372946743079324780137092704730297409327409237409237432,
... ])
23590237589734986964350281993664426765687030779425475863059795330661563273891703087477069019797
```

Python has arbitrary-size integers, that can become way larger than C's `long long`.